# What is the best way to store JSON data within mobile hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, hybrid-mobile-app

There are few options in the market to store some JSON data within mobile app (indexedDB, webSQL, etc.).

I'm looking for the best solution (which is not deprecated and which is honestly supported by commonly used browsers) to store my JSON data and simply use it within the mobile app which is created for the presentation / demo / portfolio purposes.

My static JSON file structure looks as follows:

```
{
   "products": [
      .. several records
   ],
   "users": [
      ... several records
   ],
   "factData": [
      ... few thousand records
   ]
}
```

The question is, which technology / method should I use to simply store above JSON data and do not worry about support ?

Comment: `localStorage`, is very well supported.. And very easy to use.

Comment: what do you think about localForage?
https://localforage.github.io/localForage/

Answer (score 1):

Local storage provides simple, synchronous key/value pair storage, but Performs poorly with large amounts of data and could possibly lock up UI.

WebSQL is depracated but you can still use it. You can only store around 5MB of data.

IndexedDB is not supported on IOS.

I would probabaly go with WebSQL for now, but I would look into other ways of storing the data in the JSON. Maybe create a database and an API and make authorized REST calls to it

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look into [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) that not only facilitates json storage on the client but also offline syncing to a couchdb server.

You could look at this FAQ [native support](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html#native_support)

In regards to support you'll also find some more detail on there [faq page](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html)

Comment: PouchDB seems to be interesting NoSQL way of storing data. The question is, do I need to implement any backend env. to get it work for the simple usage? 

For me, it would be enough to initially store data from my json files and have possibility to ask for them within any app view / component.

Comment: You don't need to implement any backend env with pouchdb, 
For your scenario, you could have the data passed over to the client over http then store it with pouchdb
I would also recomend you have a look at this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-offline-first-app-pouchdb/)

Comment: @Eling You could also store data as a JSON string for the case of localStorage and parse it when needed, though this might be quite inefficient if you only need a part of the data

Answer (score 0):

For your question you got many hybride app to play with json data :

Xamarin, PhoneGap, intel XDK, Ionic Framework, Framework 7, Appcelerator Titanium, Mobile Angular UI, Onsen UI, Sencha Touch, Kendo UI, all hybrid frameworks use JavaScript with more and more sensitive logic being put on the client-side so there's a need to focus on client-side security too.

So i didn't tryed all of them but is the actual list of principals app hybrid, so now javascript learning is no a option as 10 years ago :).

Comment: Yes, I know that we've got many hybrid mobile frameworks in the market and I'm using few of them but it doesn't change the fact that if you want to store some data, you have to think about it independently because none of the above frameworks does impose its own solution to store data. xD

Comment: I use ionic because is simple to getting started, a good community behind, can be associated with angular, got a powerfull UX SDK for fast development. Storing the data isn't really the job of a framework, manipulated it can. For store json data you have to jump in the work on NOSQL the big to the small solution : (cassandra the best for me, hive, hadoop, mongodb i like it too for small project ...). Regards